# Не работает драйвер PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, qt, postgresql, компиляция, psql

Есть необходимость скомпилировать драйвер PostgrSQL под Qt 5.8 под MinGW 5.3

Расскажу как было с самого начала. Под Win7 x64 стоял Qt 5.5 для MSVC2012 без Src.
Когда возникла необходимость скомпилировать драйвер, переустановил Qt на версию 5.8 с исходниками Src. Компиляция с первого раза не удалась, не подхватывались пути из PATH указывающие на библиотеки PSQL. Задача разрешилась только тогда, когда кинул libpq.dll в папку с исходниками psql. Все откомпилилось. Но драйвер все-так же не подходит. Ни единой ошибки, за которую я мог бы уцепиться. Если есть вопросы как именно я это делал, спрашивайте. Кто знает, в чем может быть дело, помогите. А то уже нервов не хватает. Я новичок, еще много чего могу не знать.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Все удалено и переставлено заново - Postgre, Qt под MinGW. После этого скомпилировалось.